# AngularJS - Manipulating a group of DOM after ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

I have a list of products, and each product has more than one color for user to choose from and when a color is clicked a tick will show up. so what I am trying to do are:

1. only one tick will show up in a group of color
2. when a user click ADD link, parameters will be passed, and tell me the product id and if a color has been chosen

***My Problems***
I could not make other ticks disappear within a group when a user click on a color.

Please use the following link and click a color for better demonstration
[this is the example](http://codepen.io/kongfupanda/pen/zGBmwp)

HTML

```
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6" ng-repeat="product in products">
             <div class="product-container">
                 <h2>{{product.name}}</h2>
                 <strong>Choose a Color</strong>
                 <div class="cycle-colors big-cycle" >
                    <i single-cycle-color ng-repeat="color in colors" class="cycle-color" bgcolor="{{color.code}}"></i>
                </div>
                <div class="text-right" >
                    <a class="add" ng-click="addProduct(product.id)" >ADD</a>
                </div>
             </div>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
    var app = angular.module('app', []);


app.controller('ProductController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {

    $scope.products = [
       {id:'1', name:'Product Name'},
       {id:'2', name:'Product Name'},
       {id:'3', name:'Product Name'},
       {id:'4', name:'Product Name'},
       {id:'5', name:'Product Name'},
       {id:'6', name:'Product Name'}

    ];

    $scope.colors = [
       {code:'#f1f3f3'},
       {code:'#b9bcbf'},
       {code:'#737d82'},
       {code:'#323237'},
       {code:'#00d7ff'},
       {code:'#0069d2'},
       {code:'#c0df16'},
       {code:'#24586e'},
       {code:'#112f3b'}
    ];

    $scope.addProduct = function(id){
            alert(id);
    }

}]);

app.directive('singleCycleColor', function () {
return {
        restrict: "AE",
        scope: {'bgcolor':'@'},
        replace:false,
        link: function (scope, element, attrbute) {

                //
                element.css('background-color', scope.bgcolor);

                // using white or black tick
                if (scope.bgcolor == '#ffffff') {
                    // using black tick
                    var tickClass = 'tick-black';
                } else {
                    // using black white tick
                    var tickClass = 'tick-white';
                }

                // on cycle click
                element.on('click', function () {

                    // add tick class
                    element.addClass(tickClass);
                    element.addClass('active');
                });

        }
    };
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- kachhalimbu's answer for your first goal (only one tick per product) is good.
- For your second goal (tell the product **ID** and if color's been checked):

  ```
               <div class="cycle-colors big-cycle" >
                  <i single-cycle-color ng-repeat="color in colors" class="cycle-color" bgcolor="{{color.code}}"
           ng-click="productColorPicked($parent.$index, color.code)"></i>
              </div>
              <div class="text-right" >
                  <a class="add" ng-click="addProduct($index)" >ADD</a>
              </div>
           </div>
  ```

To get the product ID:

- I pass the $index of the ng-repeat, and use this index to find the product in $scope.products.

To check if a color (of a product) has been selected:

- When a user selects a color, the productID (index) is passed (as well as the color, if you want).
- With this index, $scope.products[index].colorChecked becomes true.

See the working solution for your **second** goal: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/doXxBe?editors=101

Comment: Agree, this is a better solution for the second issue.

Answer (score 1):

Just remove `tickClass` from all siblings before adding it to the active one

```
angular.forEach(element.siblings(), function(sibling){
  angular.element(sibling).removeClass(tickClass);
});
```

This only solves the first problem though of making other color selections disappear.

For the second problem, you need to save the current color code selection in parent scope and pass it to the addProduct method

```
<a class="add" ng-click="addProduct(product.name, selectedColor.code)" >ADD</a>
```

in your directive

```
scope.$parent.selectedColor.code = scope.bgcolor;
```

Here is the [completed codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jPrgXO) that solves both the issues.

Comment: @kachhalimbu thanks for such quick response. However I noticed that when I click color on Product A and than directly click ADD on Product B, it will show me the color on Product A, do you think that is reasonable?

Comment: Good catch. Yeah you need product to selected color mapping. See @daCoda 's answer for that